# bootstrap - same size of input into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a table of input for a simple form where each input has a label. To center the form, I used `col-md-6 col-md-offset-3`.

My problem is that all the inputs are not the same size. Here is the resulting [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ysis81/vwx6gnx4/), and my code:

```
 <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
         <form role="form">
         <table class="table table-condensed">
         <tr>
         <td>
          <label for="lab1">Longueur 1</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab1" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab2">Longueur 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab2" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab3">Longueur 3</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" is="lab3" />
     </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab4">Masse 1</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab4" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab5">Masse 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab5" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab6">Masse 3</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" is="lab6" />
     </td>
         </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
          <label for="lab7">Angle 1</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab7" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab8">Angle 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab8" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab9">Angle 3</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" is="lab9" />
     </td>
     <td>
          <label for="lab7">Vitesse 1</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab7" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab8">Vitesse 2</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab8" />
         </td>
         <td>
          <label for="lab9">Vitesse 3</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" is="lab9" />
     </td>
         </tr>
       </table>
         </form>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
```

As you can see, for the two lines, the three "input" on the right are smaller than ones on the left.

How could I fix this and set the same size for the 12 input?

Comment: Just so you know, you have the ID's #lab7, and #lab8, and #lab9 repeated once each. Additionally, some of the ID attributes in your inputs are labeled "is".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to the label length, if you try to change one you'll see the table adjusting accordingly, just like a table should behave to be readable.

Try instead to use the Bootstrap grid, creating two `.row`s and enclosing each `label` + `input` in a `.col-xs-2`. This will ensure that you get six evenly-spaced fields.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider ditching the table altogether and using bootstrap to layout the columns - it'll make things far easier when you come to think about this on mobile devices.

As bardo has correctly said, it's due to the length of the label that the lengths are different. One option is to only display 3 elements per row on small devices, and then switch to 6 when you hit 768px (iPad screensize). For that, you'd use this code for each element:

```
...
  <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-2">
    <label for="lab1">Longueur 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab1" value="12345678" />
  </div>
...
```

Of course, you may find that is still not enough for a tiny (i.e. mobile) screen so it may even be better to show one element per line until you hit 768px:

```
...
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <label for="lab1">Longueur 1</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lab1" value="12345678" />
  </div>
...
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vwx6gnx4/8/ You'll see that on a small screen you have 4 rows of 3 elements, which means that there is space for all the labels to be displayed.